# Stop any syncing with other apple devices with same Apple ID and MacBook

Tags: macos, apple-id

How to stop at all any syncing on new MacBook with another devices with same Apple ID? I want to use Apple ID on MacBook only for **App Store**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syncing happens in the system settings, iCloud. If you sign out there, you stop syncing.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208242

You can stay signed in to the App Store and not sign in to iCloud as well, just skip the full setup when you set up your account - choose set up later if you are asked if you want to sync iCloud.

Comment: Does ‘Find My Mac’ service is will be disabled in this case? I ask like just iPhone user, have no experience to use MacOS.

Comment: Yes @Obelix - signing out of iCloud entirely removes find my. Also, once you disable everything - you can be very granular if you sign in again. You can choose to enable only the one or several classes you wish.